# Wrap around and around and around and around and around and around and around and around and around

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, cipher

Can you build a message from these few sparse pieces?

```
ALL···············L···········HE······················L··E·O············E·······················OR········T··E····


THE··········E···········S··············O··········O·A·····E························E····················E······O·


EF···············N·T·E···························O·····························E····E···T···········W····L········


A···N··········F······················O·····E····E······T··············A····R·····R·······························
```

Maybe with enough wrapping you can!  Let's get started:

```
ALL···············L···········HE······················L··E·O············E·······················OR········T··E····

 +

ALL···············L···········HE······················L··E·O············E·······················OR········T··E····

 =

ALL···············LOR········THEE····ALL··············LL·E·O·······HE···E··················L··E·OR········T··E····
```

```
THE··········E···········S··············O··········O·A·····E························E····················E······O·

 +

THE··········E···········S··············O··········O·A·····E························E····················E······O·

 =

THE··········ES··········S···O··········O·A·····E··O·A·····E·············E··········E·········E······O·THE······O·
```

```
EF···············N·T·E···························O·····························E····E···T···········W····L········

 +

EF···············N·T·E···························O·····························E····E···T···········W····L········

 =

EF···············N·T·E···O·······················O·····E····E···T···········W··E·L··E···T·EF········W····L·N·T·E··
```

```
A···N··········F······················O·····E····E······T··············A····R·····R·······························

 +

A···N··········F······················O·····E····E······T··············A····R·····R·······························

 =

AT··N··········FA····R·····R··········O·····E····E······T··A···N·······A··F·R·····R··············O·····E····E·····
```

It's not everything you need, but it should be enough to get you rolling:

```
ALL···············LOR········THEE····ALL··············LL·E·O·······HE···E··················L··E·OR········T··E····

 +

THE··········ES··········S···O··········O·A·····E··O·A·····E·············E··········E·········E······O·THE······O·

 +

EF···············N·T·E···O·······················O·····E····E···T···········W··E·L··E···T·EF········W····L·N·T·E··

 +

AT··N··········FA····R·····R··········O·····E····E······T··A···N·······A··F·R·····R··············O·····E····E·····

 =

??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cycling the four pieces, there is only one way that they fit together and that gives us the following message:

> `AT·ONAN·THEE··OFALL··RE····R·····LL·E·O·····E·HE·E·E·T··TE·A···NOWTHE·LA·EFORTHEF·R··T··EWES·ALLNOT·E·SEF·O·E··LOR`

Near the end I see

> we can fill in some letters to get the excerpt "we shall not cease", googling which gave me a T.S. Eliot poem.

Cycling the string and adding the missing letters we get

> the first few lines of the poem,
>
>   WESHALLNOTCEASEFROMEXPLORATIONANDTHEENDOFALLOUREXPLORINGWILLBETOARRIVEWHEREWESTARTEDANDKNOWTHEPLACEFORTHEFIRSTTIME

Or with spaces and line breaks,

> We shall not cease from exploration
>   And the end of all our exploring
>   Will be to arrive where we started
>   And know the place for the first time.

An apt verse!